# Emission shader low resolution in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, emission

I do the following:

- I start a new project
- I add a new material to the cube
- I add emission volume

Then the emission appears with low resolution. If i add the material to a sphere, the emission appears cube-shaped.

How do I get a high resolution or a sphere-shaped emission?

[image: render settings]

[image: viewport]

Answer (score 0):

Eeevee only supports box-shaped volumes. To increase the resolution bump up the tile size and samples in rendering/volumetrics.